# How to add a dockable window in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I want to add one of those dockable windows panes, such as the solution explorer in visual studio 2008 to my project, are they in fact called dockable tool, or shims?  And where do I find it because obviously its not in the default list?

Comment: What technology are you using? WinForms, WPF, WebForms, SilverLight? Also, please don't duplicate the tags ("C#") in the title. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Sorry John.  The technology is WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in control in .Net that does this; you need a third-party docking suite.

Commercial ones include [DevExpress XtraBars](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/Index.xml).
Free ones include [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good reference

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140209/Building-a-Docking-Window-Management-Solution-in-W